# Google Calendar displays events twice

Tags: google-calendar

I have just installed Google Calendar on my Samsung Galaxy S8+. The calendar is synced from my outlook.com Exchange ActiveSync. Events that are created elsewhere (not created from the Google Calendar in my S8+) are displayed twice. They are NOT duplicates, merely displaying an event twice.

[image]

In the screenshot above, "Blood test" is actually just ONE event but being displayed as two items. If I delete any ONE of the items, the event will be deleted and both items will be removed. This event was created from other device.

If I were to create an event from within Google Calendar on my S8+ itself, then the event is displayed as expected - displayed only once, as in the case of "Test Event" above.

When I'm using Samsung Calendar (the stock Calendar app), it doesn't have this problem.

How can I have those events being displayed once only on my Google Calendar?

Comment: Do you have two email ids? If yes, click on 3 horizontal showing in screen on top left and uncheck events and reminders of other email id.